# handling special character '/' in grid view TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to concatenate two data fields in template field via '/'character but I am getting error as ::

```
The server tag is not well formed.
```

How should I handle the special character in `TemplateField`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FATHER NAME / MOTHER NAME">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FATHER_NAME") + " '/' " + Eval("MOTHER_NAME")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested but this should work.

```
Text='<%# Eval("FATHER_NAME") + "/" + Eval("MOTHER_NAME")%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a method in code behind file

```
protected string GetParentsName(string fatherName, string montherName)
{
   return Convert.ToString(fatherName) + "/" + Convert.ToString(montherName);   
}
```

Call it for each row from aspx file like below:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# GetParentsName(Eval("FATHER_NAME") as string, Eval("MOTHER_NAME") as string) %>' />
```